# timezone reconciliation with SQL

Tags: mysql, go, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

#### Question 1/3:

I have a number of `MySQL` databases to connect to and want to ensure time consistency across queries. So for example, one of these servers is currently in the `CDT` timezone.

```
> select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @@system_time_zone, @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;

+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | @@system_time_zone | @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-05-31 09:44:45 | CDT                | SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Note: We're in `DST` right now, so it's `CDT`. I'm *assuming* this would automatically change to `CST` when outside `DST`, right?

So with the above knowledge, my `DSN` suffix looks something like this:

```
...?parseTime=true&loc=America%2FChicago // i.e. 'America/Chicago' - maybe 'CST6CDT' would work too?
```

So, is there a programatic way in `go` to map from the 3-letter code `CDT` to the more formal timezone names like `America/Chicago`.

#### 2/3:

The above presents a chicken/egg scenario: in order to determine the remote server's timezone, one needs to connect/query the server; with that knowledge the DSN parameters may change for future calls.

Can DSN parameters be changed after the fact, or does a brand new connection `sql.DB` connection pool need to be created?

#### 3/3:

You may ask, why check to see if the timezone has changed - isn't it static? What should one do in a Load-Balanced DB situation? Two replicas could in theory be in differing timezones?

Should all columns with timestamps just be wrapped with an SQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to normalize the data and avoid this headache?

I could get into time-drifts too, but I'll stop here for now.

Comment: The system time zone should `America/Chicago`.  If it's `CDT`, it's likely set wrong on the system.  What OS is the system anyway?

Comment: Keep in mind that time zone abbreviations can sometimes be derived from time zone identifiers, but not usually the other way around.  There's just too much ambiguity.  The C in CST could just as well be for China or Cuba.

Comment: @MattJohnson yep - that's the conclusion I came to also. Rather than reverse engineer how MySQL reports the timezone, the simplest approach was to normalize the time from within the SQL query, so `go` would get UTC times and thus not need to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1/3

`go` uses IANA's [Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) with precise zone names.
Trying to reverse engineer how MySQL determines the local timezone format from a (Linux) host and duplicate that logic in a `go` clients - as @MattJohnson pointed out - proves to be unreliable.

#### 2/3

`database/sql.DB` - created via `Open(drv, DSN)` - will use the same `DSN` for all connections. While an `sql.DB` is meant to be created once and used many times - there is no way to change the `DSN` after the fact - so one would need to create a brand new `sql.DB` when changing the `DSN`.

#### 3/3

So the better tack, appears to leverage `MySQL` to convert all `datetime` values from local to UTC timezone before transmission to the client. This removes the complication of setting the database's (possibly unknown) timezone at connection time via the `DSN`.

One promising option, is to set the connection's session timezone:

- `SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";`
- however, this only works for the *current* connection (within the connection pool). A `go` client however will not know which free connection they may be using at any give time.
- So to ensure this always works, one would need to apply it manually before ***all queries***. Even if only one DB connection is in use - if the connection fails and connection retry kicks in - any previous session state would be lost.

So instead, wrapping all `datatime` columns with a conversion function like so:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`STAMP_UPDATED`,@@session.time_zone,'+00:00')
```

ensures the timezone calculation is done at query time and will not be lost during a connection reconnection etc.

So now the `DSN` no longer needs to specify `loc` - as `UTC` is the default. In fact the `DSN` only needs the suffix option of `?parseTime=true` to allow the `datetime` to be translated into `go`'s native `time.Time`.

Finally and most importantly, this will work with any server set to any timezone.

H/T to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/1218512).