# How to interpret these timestamps

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, timestamp, google-cloud-datastore, datetime-format

I have different values in Google datastore column *TS*. The column **type** is `string`. Here are bunch of values

```
1994-11-04T13:15:30Z    
1994-11-06T13:15:30Z    
1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00   
1994-11-07T08:15:30-05:00
```

Now these values are in 2 different formats. The one with `Z` represent the timestamp in UTC timezone. However, the one with the offset is representing local timezone (am I correct here?)

Now the problem is that the query that we are making in our project does ordering based on this column i.e.,

```
query := datastore.NewQuery(myEntityType).
    Namespace(myNameSpace.String()).
    Order("-TS")
rows := make([]domain.datastore.rows, 0)
_, err := r.client.GetAll(ctx, query, rows)
```

There `client` is `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` object.

I am unable to test this in my local but in prod, the end user are seeing these things out of order. However, if I go to datastore UI, and sort values by clicking on `TS` column, they order just fine. Which is confusing me that if the error was on sorting, shouldn't the error be there on UI as well?

So I am not sure how to fix this bug. Should I convert Google Datastore column to Timestamp (can we do so?). Or should I fix the code to persist consistently?

Comment: I ran into this headache recently. It's best to normalize your times into UTC. If your DB is reporting times in local-time, best to coerce them into UTC at the query stage e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397882/timezone-reconciliation-with-sql

Comment: Those are [RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) formatted times.

Comment: Both of them? or just with the offset?